# Heating element in soldering irons

Tags: soldering-iron-station

Are there ever cases that the heating element is in the base of a soldering iron? I thought that the heating element is almost always in the wand, and the base just provides the power, but a friend thinks otherwise.

Comment: I have seen hot air wands with the  heating element in the base.

Comment: If your friend is still unconvinced, ask them: What is the job of a soldering iron? To heat your hand or to heat the solder on the tip of the iron? The best soldering irons have one piece tip/elements so you have full power right at the tip at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense for the heater to be in the base, since the heat needs to be conducted all the way to the wand, resulting in a large loss. A coil in the wand generates the heat, and the base only contains circuitry that regulates the electricity being sent to the wand.

Answer (score 5):

There certainly are, and they have the advantage of being cordless.

[image]

The "base" would be a blacksmith's forge, or a brazing hearth or a small gas burner or oven.

I've never seen one used in the electronics industry though...

Comment: My grandfather had one of those.  He'd heat it by putting it in the fire of a small camp stove.  It's not exactly temperature controlled, but he didn't use it for electronic soldering.

Answer (score 1):

There are microwave soldering irons. Not that the heating element is in the station, but the electrical power is spent there. Then the microwaves carry it to the wand.